# Why loading parquet files into Bigquery gives me back gibberish values into the table?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When I load parquet files into Bigquery table, values stored are wierd. It seems to be the encoding of BYTES fields or whatever else.

[image]

Here's the format of the create fields

[image]

So when I read the table with casted fields, I get the readable values.

[image]

I found the solution [here](https://medium.com/@david.alvares.62/gcp-tips-chips-n-2-gibberish-33718a25d22f)

Ma question is WHY TF bigquery is bahaving like this?

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Comment: Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.
The goal here is not to post my code but to show how Bigquery behave when it load my parquet files. I dont have another way to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#type_conversions), there are some parquet data types that can be converted into multiple BigQuery data types. A workaround is to add the data type that you want to parse to BigQuery.

For example, to convert the Parquet INT32 data type to the BigQuery DATE data type, specify the following:

`optional int32 date_col (DATE);`

And another way is to add the schema to the bq load [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#parquet_schemas):

```
bq load --source_format=PARQUET --noreplace --noautodetect --parquet_enum_as_string=true --decimal_target_types=STRING [project]:[dataset].[tables] gs://[bucket]/[file].parquet  Column_name:Data_type
```